# How to make $(Set, +, \phi)$ into a symmetric monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, monoidal-categories

Here $+$ denotes disjoint union. I am working on showing that $(Set, + , \phi)$ is a symmetric monoidal category. When I got to defining the symmetry morphisms I ran into trouble because I have been regarding $X+Y$ to be strictly equal to $Y+X$. Thus I am not sure how to define a map $\beta \colon X+Y \to Y+X$ which is not the identity but has the required properties.

Comment: What is your definition of $X+Y$?

Comment: The identity doesn't have the required properties?

Comment: @Randall: No matter how you define $X+Y$, the identity will not be the correct map in the case $X=Y\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: @EricWofsey : when $X=Y=\emptyset, X+Y=\emptyset$ and so there's only one choice for a function : the identity. OP : $X+Y\neq Y+X$ in general. That's because arbitrary sets aren't disjoints, and you want a notion of disjoint union to be applicable to arbitrary sets, so you can't just say "it's $\cup$". When they have elements in common you need to find a way to tag those elements in different ways and this requires, by design, some sort of asymmetry between the first and the second component.

Comment: Of course this asymmetry is mild and goes away when you look at $+$ as a functor, up to natural isomorphism (if you defined $+$ properly, so that it works as a coproduct). What I suggest you do is rather prove that a triple $(C, +, 0)$ where $C$ is a category, $+$ is a coproduct functor, and $0$ an initial object, is always symmetric monoidal (if I'm not mostaken, it should be true)

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: Thank you Max your comment answers my question. I needed to be more careful in how I define disjoint union. $\phi$ Is the empty set.